# How to do permanently replace list with new lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def group_together(players, team):
    coplayers = list(players)
    players = []
    players_team = []
    num_players= len(coplayers)
    no_groups = num_players // team
    if num_players%team > 0:
        no_groups += 1
    c = 0
    for i in range(no_groups):
        players_team.append([])
        for j in range(team):
            if c < num_players:
                players_team[i].append(coplayers[c])
                c+=1
    players = players_team

players = [456, 218, 67, 1, 101, 199]
group_together(players, 2)#nothing is returned
print(players)
```

Output:

```
[[456, 218], [67, 1], [101, 199]]
```

I'm trying to replace the players with the new groupings of it but when I run the code with the test code it does not print the new players in groups, but instead, it prints the old unmodified players.

Is there any way to fix this? If so I would be very grateful.

Comment: Python doesn't have call-by-reference semantics. If you want a value back from a function, you need to return it.

Comment: But I am not trying to return it I'm trying to modify players.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: I want the outcome to be [[456, 218], [67, 1], [101, 199]] but it comes out as [456, 218, 67, 1, 101, 199] instead.

Comment: I tried using players.clear() but the output comes out as empty []

Comment: if I do players.clear() is there a way to make sure that players = players_team does not cause a problem?

Comment: I know that using extend works but how do I do it without using extend?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that's true in most cases, but because lists are mutable you can do it.  Just take out the `players = []` and use `players[:] = players_team` at the end.

Comment: then is there a way to put them into groupings without slicing and using extend?

Comment: Without using slicing or extend you can't modify the list that was passed to you.  Reassigning it the way you did only changes the list you see inside the function, not what you see outside the function.

Comment: See [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/5987)

Comment: Why all of the artificial restrictions? You refuse to use function return values, slice notation, or the `extend` function? Add a few more restrictions and this question would be more appropriate as a restricted-source challenge on CodeGolf SE.

Answer (score 0):

'players' it's considered as new local variable inside the function.
Instead of `players=[]` you can use `players.clear()`,
and `players.append(players_team)`to assign the value

```
def group_together(players, team):
    coplayers = list(players)
    players.clear()
    players_team = []
    num_players= len(coplayers)
    no_groups = num_players // team
    if num_players%team > 0:
        no_groups += 1
    c = 0
    for i in range(no_groups):
        players_team.append([])
        for j in range(team):
            if c < num_players:
                players_team[i].append(coplayers[c])
                c+=1
    players.append(players_team)
```